# Logrotate does not work daily, but the status file says it does

Tags: linux, logging, log-files, logrotate, log-rotation

This is my `logrotate` script:

```
/var/log/pyApi.log /var/log/runGet*.log {
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 7
    compress
    notifempty
    nocreate
    su
}
```

Already checked `/var/lib/logrotate/status`, it says the last run is on 27 February 2016, but the last updated log in `var/log` is on 23 February 2016. Why is that?

The log is generated from an Upstart script.

Comment: 'ls -l ' from your /var/log will be useful . Have you reloaded logrotate service after changes to conf ?

Comment: Sure! Please see here: http://pastebin.com/xnyR8fgT Yup, I have reloaded it.

Comment: Thinking it is not rotating because there is no file named pyApi.log  or runGet*.log . You shoulf check the path of your logging files in your app.

Comment: @kranteg, the log doesn't exist because the previously existing log is zipped by the logrotate. What should I do to make sure logrotate keeps working even after the original file gets zipped.